# Смысл предложения: необходимо направить нам фото в хорошем качестве подписанного с Вашей стороны договора (все страницы)

Tags: смысл, значение

Что имеется в виду в предложении „необходимо направить нам фото в хорошем качестве подписанного с Вашей стороны договора (все страницы)“? Отправить фото всех страниц или отправить фото всех подписанных страниц (a место для  подписи есть только на первой и последней страницах)?
Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Если на странице нет места для подписи, то им не нужно фото этой страницы, поэтому конечно фотографии страниц с местом для подписи и подписью. Но это, конечно, вопрос не для этого форума.

Comment: Это есть вопрос для этого форума - определить смысл предложения.